# Trouble building gcc on Mac - can't find system headers

Tags: macos, gcc

I'm on a Mac running OS-X High Sierra and wanted to create a separate build of gcc.  Lemme share a little of the process it took me a week to work out so it will help others:

I made a safe directory "gcc" and used svn to get the latest source code from gcc, which it created in a subdirectory called "trunk".  I initially created a directory called "build" in the top level of trunk.

It wouldn't compile without the 4 dependencies, so I ran ./contrib/download prerequisites to get them, but it still wouldn't compile, so I went into each of those 4 directories individually and did ./configure, ./make, ./make install, and ./make check.  I did the install part because even these dependencies depended on each other, so installing seemed like a safe way to make sure they could be found.  Later I found out there is no other way, despite instructions to the contrary...

I succeeded in building the dependencies GMP, MPFR, ISL, and MPC.  Then I went back to ./build and the ../configure succeeded, but the build (make) quickly failed saying "source directory already configured; run "make distclean there first".  Googling showed this was when you configure in the source directory.  I thought maybe my trunk/build directory was considered "in the source directory", so I moved it and tried again and the same thing happened.  When I tried to go into trunk and type "make distclean" is just said No rule to make target distclean.

So I thought, maybe it's the 4 dependency directories?  Maybe now that they're installed it's safe to distclean them all?  There, make distclean worked and took out everything - even the tests I ran.  Seems wasteful and necessitates pre make-installing them, but it worked.

Back in build, make then started some serious compile work during the make, but crashed saying "the directory that should contain system headers does not exist: /usr/include".

How should I bootstrap this?  Where would I find the system headers to copy into /usr/include?  And will I have the same problem with missing libc and libraries later on?  Also, if I want to transplant this to a new computer without rebuilding, what do I need to copy besides the executables and the headers?  And where would I put them?

Thanks for any advice...
- Jeff

Comment: Update - it appears in high sierra, even with sudo I cannot make a directory in /usr, so I cannot make a directory /usr/include.  I have read online that you can set environment variables to change where gcc looks for standard headers ($CPATH), but setting that seemed to have no effect.

Comment: Why would you do any of that? Use **hombrew** and type `brew install gcc` and you're all done.

Comment: Update2:  After Googling, I'm going to try the --with-gxx-include-dir=dirname option with the initial configure.  However, this may not work, since it sounds like it specifies where to install the headers, rather than where to read them from.  I'll letcha know if this solves it.

Comment: Actually, using homebrew ended up bricking my laptop.  Actually, to be more precise, it messed up all the directory paths and library versions and made it so I cannot bootstrap ANYTHING - as a result, I could not build gcc or llvm by any means on that system - not with homebrew, not with macports - not directly.  After Googling I saw a lot of things advising me to NEVER use homebrew for making gcc.  My hope here is to use the backup (not ruined) computer to produce a working gcc that I can somehow use to fix the original laptop that was ruining from the homebrew install.

Comment: To be fair to homebrew, I saw a lot of warnings from gcc themselves saying that if you install gcc on an existing non-gcc system you risk making the system completely non-functional.  And that's what happened to me.  :( . So this is just one part of a much much bigger problem.  Fortunately, the XCode stack never faltered (and I reinstalled it to be safe), but my ability to make ANY package on that laptop has failed.  :(

Comment: OK, Mark inspired me to try brew again.  To be more specific, I *can* do brew install gcc, and it does build a gcc.  But you need 3 things - the exe, the libraries, and the headers.  And I always fail on the latter 2.  In this case, using gcc to compile anything yields: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/isl/lib/libisl.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0/7.2.0/cc1
  Reason: image not found
When I look there, I have version 19.  When I make an alias and call i t version 15, then I get the next library not found error.

Comment: Maybe the brew recipe is just out of date?

Comment: UPDATE3:  Created a directory /opt/gcc/include and copied the XCode gcc include files there.  Then did a configure using the two options for standard include directories.  And now it failed because it could find .a libraries.  It DEFINITELY sounds like the high sierra loss of /usr/include has screwed up the standard installations.  Time to start a bounty.  Who can help me compile gcc in High Sierra?

Answer (score 11):

I managed to hackily get GCC building on macOS Sierra with Xcode 8.3.3. Try the following on your system. (You might need to make some tweaks if you have a newer version of macOS or a newer version of Xcode.)

## Prerequisites

- macOS Sierra 10.12.6
- Xcode 8.3.3

Details:

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Users/strager/Applications/Xcode_8.3.3.app/Contents/Developer

$ clang --version                     
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/strager/Applications/Xcode_8.3.3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

$ as --version
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/strager/Applications/Xcode_8.3.3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

$ ld -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-278.4
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em (tvOS)
LTO support using: LLVM version 8.1.0, (clang-802.0.42)
TAPI support using: Apple TAPI version 1.33.11
```

## Configuring and building

```
$ # Download GCC's source code.
$ git clone git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git gcc
$ # I tested the following revision (SVN r278004 from November 9, 2019):
$ (cd gcc && git checkout a9ad50cb8ec15c509d27c1dbd47b76f56d20fb3b)
$ # Download GCC's uncommon dependencies.
$ ./contrib/download_prerequisites
$ # Apply a build fix: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2019-11/msg01109.html
$ patch -p1 <<<EOF
diff --git a/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/alloc_traits.h
b/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/alloc_traits.h
index 55211ac1d72..6ad02df16f7 100644
--- a/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/alloc_traits.h
+++ b/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/alloc_traits.h
@@ -566,7 +566,7 @@ _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION
 #endif

   template<typename _Alloc>
-    _GLIBCXX14_CONSTEXPR void
+    _GLIBCXX14_CONSTEXPR inline void
     __alloc_on_copy(_Alloc& __one, const _Alloc& __two)
     {
       typedef allocator_traits<_Alloc> __traits;
@@ -580,7 +580,7 @@ _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION
     }

   template<typename _Alloc>
-    constexpr _Alloc
+    constexpr inline _Alloc
     __alloc_on_copy(const _Alloc& __a)
     {
       typedef allocator_traits<_Alloc> __traits;
@@ -598,7 +598,7 @@ _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION
 #endif

   template<typename _Alloc>
-    _GLIBCXX14_CONSTEXPR void
+    _GLIBCXX14_CONSTEXPR inline void
     __alloc_on_move(_Alloc& __one, _Alloc& __two)
     {
       typedef allocator_traits<_Alloc> __traits;
@@ -625,7 +625,7 @@ _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION
 #endif

   template<typename _Alloc>
-    _GLIBCXX14_CONSTEXPR void
+    _GLIBCXX14_CONSTEXPR inline void
     __alloc_on_swap(_Alloc& __one, _Alloc& __two)
     {
       typedef allocator_traits<_Alloc> __traits;
EOF

$ # Configure a build directory for a 3-stage build.
$ mkdir gcc-build-release
$ cd gcc-build-release
$ ../gcc/configure \
    --disable-werror \
    --enable-checking=release \
    --enable-languages=c,c++ \
    --prefix="${PWD}/../usr" \
    --with-native-system-header-dir=/Users/strager/Applications/Xcode_8.3.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/ \
    --disable-multilib

$ # Build.
$ flags='-mmacosx-version-min=10.12 -Wa,-mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -iframework /Users/strager/Applications/Xcode_8.3.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/' ; \
    make -w -j9 BOOT_CFLAGS="${flags}" CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="${flags}" CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="${flags}"
```

---

## Troubleshooting

**Problem**: Building fails:

> the directory that should contain system headers does not exist: /usr/include

**Cause**: GCC's configure scripts default to `--with-native-system-header-dir=/usr/include`. That director does not exist.

**Solution**: Configure with `--with-native-system-header-dir=/Users/strager/Applications/Xcode_8.3.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/`.

---

**Problem**: Linking or configuring fails:

> checking whether the C compiler works... no
>   configure: error: in `/Users/strager/tmp/Projects/gcc/build-release/x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0/libgomp':
>   configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

config.log shows:

> ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o

or any of the following:

> ld: library not found for -ldylib1.o
>   ld: library not found for -ldylib1.10.5.o

**Cause**: The value of `-mmacosx-version-min=` given to the linker driver doesn't match the SDK in Xcode. [GCC tries to link the wrong objects](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/a9ad50cb8ec15c509d27c1dbd47b76f56d20fb3b/gcc/config/darwin.h#L430-L448).

**Solution**: Build stages 2 and 3 with `-mmacosx-version-min=10.12` (for Xcode 8.3.3's `MacOSX10.12.sdk`) using the `BOOT_CFLAGS`, `CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET`, and `CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET` make variables.

---

**Problem**: libstdc++.6.dylib fails to link:

> 0  0x1059a453b  __assert_rtn + 129
>   1  0x1059a940a  mach_o::relocatable::CUSection::personalityName(mach_o::relocatable::Parser&, macho_relocation_info > const*) + 170
>   2  0x1059b8c2e  mach_o::relocatable::CUSection::parse(mach_o::relocatable::Parser&, unsigned int, mach_o::relocatable::CUSection::Info*) + 306
>   3  0x1059b666b  mach_o::relocatable::Parser::parse(mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 695
>   4  0x1059af1c9  mach_o::relocatable::Parser::parse(unsigned char const*, unsigned long long, char const*, long, ld::File::Ordinal, mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 261
>   5  0x1059d9758  archive::File::makeObjectFileForMember(archive::File::Entry const*) const + 748
>   6  0x1059d8b8c  archive::File::forEachAtom(ld::File::AtomHandler&) const + 238
>   7  0x1059f2955  ld::tool::InputFiles::forEachInitialAtom(ld::File::AtomHandler&, ld::Internal&) + 533
>   8  0x1059fe49c  ld::tool::Resolver::resolve() + 44
>   9  0x1059a5289  main + 725
>   A linker snapshot was created at:
>           /tmp/libstdc++.6.dylib-2019-10-13-002048.ld-snapshot
>   ld: Assertion failed: ((parser.sectionForAddress(personalityAddr)->type() == ld::Section::typeCode) && "personality column in __compact_unwind section is not pointer to function"), function personalityName, file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ld64/ld64-278.4/src/ld/parsers/macho_relocatable_file.cpp, line 5128.
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

**Cause**: [LLVM's assembler (`as`) generates `__compact_unwind` sections](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/19a71f6bdf2dddb10764939e7f0ec2b98dba76c9/llvm/lib/MC/MCObjectFileInfo.cpp#L25-L48). Despite [GCC linking with `-no_compact_unwind`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/a9ad50cb8ec15c509d27c1dbd47b76f56d20fb3b/gcc/config/darwin.h#L188-L196), ld64 validates the `__compact_unwind` sections. The data is malformed (to cause unknown), so the linker complains.

**Solution**: Tell the assembler to not generate `__compact_unwind` sections using `-Wa,-mmacos-version-min=10.5` for stages 2 and 3 using the `BOOT_CFLAGS`, `CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET`, and `CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET` make variables.

---

**Problem**: libstdc++.6.dylib fails to link:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "__ZSt15__alloc_on_copyISaIcEEvRT_RKS1_", referenced from:
>         __ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE6assignERKS4_ in libstdc++.a(string-inst.o)
>     "__ZSt15__alloc_on_moveISaIcEEvRT_S2_", referenced from:
>         __ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEaSEOS4_ in libstdc++.a(string-inst.o)
>     "__ZSt15__alloc_on_swapISaIcEEvRT_S2_", referenced from:
>         __ZN9__gnu_cxx14__alloc_traitsISaIcEcE10_S_on_swapERS1_S3_ in libstdc++.a(string-inst.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

**Cause**: [`-fno-implicit-templates`](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2019-11/msg01109.html) causes these symbols to not be created, even though they are necessary.

**Solution**: [Mark function templates inline](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2019-11/msg01109.html).

---

**Problem**: ASAN (libsanitizer) fails to compile:

> In file included from ../../../../gcc/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_mac.cpp:64:
>   ../../../../gcc/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_malloc_mac.inc:20:10: fatal error: CoreFoundation/CFBase.h: No such file or directory
>      20 | #include

**Cause**: GCC isn't told where CoreFoundation is in Xcode's SDK.

**Solution**: Build stages 2 and 3 with `-iframework .../SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks` using the `BOOT_CFLAGS`, `CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET`, and `CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET` make variables.

Comment: This was an absolute godsend of an answer, thanks a lot! May I ask why you have both `-mmacosx-version-min=10.12` and `-mmacosx-version-min=10.5`? This seems counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: @WillEccles -mmacosx-version-min=10.12 is for GCC's linker driver (to solve "Problem: Linking or configuring fails"), and -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 is for Clang's assembler (to solve "Problem: libstdc++.6.dylib fails to link").

Comment: I do not understand the solution of the last problem, which says "Build stages 2 and 3 with -iframework .../SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks using the BOOT_CFLAGS, CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET, and CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET make variables.". How can I build with -iframework only on stage 2 and 3?

Answer (score 3):

There is a great blog post by Paul Silisteanu that describes the process in detail: [Compiling GCC 9 on macOS Mojave](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/05/21/compiling-gcc-macos/).

The short version is:

1) macOS 10.14 Mojave moved the system headers, which is one reason building GCC from source is tricky. However, Apple provides an installer to replace them.

```
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/
open .
```

This will open a window in the Finder, install the package. Note that this isn't guaranteed to be there in future OS updates.

2) Build the dependencies:

- [GNU GMP](https://gmplib.org)
- [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/)
- [MPC](http://www.multiprecision.org/mpc/download.html)
- [ISL](http://isl.gforge.inria.fr)

Each of these are straightforward and require nothing special (but install in this order).

3) The blog post recommends this configuration (assuming version 9.1). You can place the dependencies in other locations, just specify where.

```
mkdir build && cd build
../configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-9.1 \
             --enable-checking=release \
             --with-gmp=/usr/local/gcc-9.1 \
             --with-mpfr=/usr/local/gcc-9.1 \
             --with-mpc=/usr/local/gcc-9.1 \
             --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran \
             --with-isl=/usr/local/gcc-9.1 \
             --program-suffix=-9.1
```

The program suffix is optional, but nice to "special case" this compiler so as not to confuse it with clang.

These are the condensed instructions for the experienced user; see the blog post for a more detailed and guided tour.

Comment: Amazing article. The updated verison for MacOS 10.15+ is at https://solarianprogrammer.com/2019/10/12/compiling-gcc-macos/

Answer (score 0):

OK, nothing I mentioned above worked at all - none of the gcc build flags worked.  But I *finally* fixed my system in a simple way:  The problem is you need gcc to make gcc, and I could not even do brew install gcc - it would crash with the broken C++ library.

But then I realized that XCode comes with a safe, completely self contained (if out of date) clang/llvm toolchain - it's practically like having a docker.  To find where exactly it put everything, I used the command `xcodebuild -find x` (replacing "x" with `make`, `gcc`, `clang`, etc).  I found that everything gcc needed to build was here:

```
export PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Once that was in my path, make went there and used XCode's gcc, which was new enough to build or install modern gcc, so THEN I could do:

```
brew reinstall gcc
```

And by golly, I finally got a fully functional gcc toolchain.  Brew put it in `/usr/local/bin` etc.

That was harder than I ever thought it would be.  Since you need gcc to make gcc, how did it ever come into existence? ;)

Comment: To be fair, when building gcc from scratch, they warn you that if you install gcc on your system there's a chance you could break your OS.  And it is quite dangerous as I found out - I had to go a long time without being able to program outside of XCode.

Comment: That's what the --prefix=/some/safe/path is for, right?